# SQL - New lines in SQL commands causes migration errors?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new with SQL but I have a series of migrations that I am running.

The first migration is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id SERIAL UNIQUE,
    blah TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

The second migration is:

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

That all seems to work fine.

However, when the second migration adds some new lines:

```
ALTER TABLE
    test
ADD PRIMARY KEY
    (
        id
    )
;
```

The migration fails but pasting the above into a management console still runs the command successfully.

The migration fails with error:

```
error performing migration to latest version: migration failed: relation \"test\" does not exist in line 0: ALTER TABLE\n    test\nADD PRIMARY KEY\n    (\n        id\n    )\n;
```

Why does one work and the other does not? Are the new lines actually what is causing the failures?

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo in the question, but your first create table statement will fail because of an extra comma.

Comment: Thanks for that. I deleted some other lines and forgot to remove the comma. Edited the original post.